# What is node.js excatly?

Tags: sockets, node.js, web, websocket

i am new to web sockets and node .. I am confused  with different terminologies used with node.js. Few places it's mentioned it's a tool, few others it's a JavaScript program / any platform or some times it's an sdk at server side. Please tell me what exactly is this ode.js?

How do i write program using websockets.io in windows machine (server-side) for a client app written using web sockets. Or is there any better implementation than websockets.io for producing a faster response.. or high speed?

Comment: It's a bit of a vague question, but as for WebSockets, [DNode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) is pretty nifty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to install "exress" module to use socket.io [for simplicity you should use "express". otherwise you can implement socket.io by other way too.]

To install express write in your terminal

```
npm install express
```

Then install socket.io module for that you should write in teminal

```
npm install socket.io
```

Make file app.js
Write code as below

```
 var express = require('express')
  , stylus = require('stylus')
  , nib = require('nib')
  , sio = require('socket.io');

app.listen(3001);
var io = sio.listen(app);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.redirect('/views/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.emit('hi',{"This is first Message from socket.io"});
});
```

Then make file index.html in views folder

in it write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" ></script>

    <script>
         $(function(){
          var socket = io.connect();
              socket.on('hi',function(Message){
                   alert(Message); // Will alert "This is first Message from socket.io"
              });
         });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://nodejs.org/ is the best source of info on the topic. This is the [synopsis](http://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html).